# How to share validation rules(constraints) from JAVA backend to JS frontend

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, validation

I will try to describe my validation problem. We use some java server endpoint (e.g. spring boot) where we use validation like this:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;

public class User {

    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 200, message 
      = "About Me must be between 10 and 200 characters")
    private String aboutMe;

    @Min(value = 18, message = "Age should not be less than 18")
    @Max(value = 150, message = "Age should not be greater than 150")
    private int age;

    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;


}
```

But we need to have the same constrains in fronted (e.g. React JS). How to share those definitions of rules? Is it possible to create from all POJO class new validation POJO which can I export to JSON and use for validation in react?

For example:

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": {
      "rule": {
          "notNull": "true"
          },
      "message": "Name cannot be null"
    },
    "aboutMe": {
      "rule": {
          "size": "true",
          "min": "10",
          "max": "200"
          },
      "message": "About Me must be between 10 and 200 characters"
    }
  }

}
```